# Password protect a specific category page/post

Tags: categories, security, password

I have searched high and low for this but nothing is sticking out at me.  I am looking to password protect posts and/or pages based on a certain category.

The reason for this is that I am creating a "members" side of things and want to keep things simple.  If the post/page is in that category then users will enter a pre-defined password.  I'd like to stay away from user/roles as i think it would be easier to change password every month and "members" being notified of such change rather than maintaining who's what.

Hope someone can help me. If anything above doesn't make sense please comment :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this plugin is what you are looking for: [Private Suite.](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/private-suite/)

It specifies private categories, in which all posts will automatically be set to private.
*(It looks like this plugin in combination with user roles is watertight and a one time config)*

Found also this plugin: [Private categories](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/private-category/) , perhaps this one forfills your need even better.

Comment: Thanks for this but neither plugins really suit. What concerns me more is that neither have been updated this year. I'll install and play about though :) If it works will mark as answer. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread, but if anyone lands here from searching, I found one that works! It's called Cat-Pass. http://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/cat-pass Currently has one one-star review, but I found that it worked great. It will show the titles of posts within a category, but when you go to click on them, you have to enter a password to see the post. The "unlock" button you press appears to be in German, but if you can overlook that it's totally functional.